# Combine multi columns to one column Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have the following dataframe

```
   z  a   b   c 
   a  1   NaN NaN
   ss NaN 2   NaN
   cc 3   NaN NaN
   aa NaN 4   NaN
   ww NaN 5   NaN
   ss NaN NaN 6
   aa NaN NaN 7
   g  NaN NaN 8
   j  9   NaN NaN
```

I would like to create a new column d to do something like this

```
z  a   b   c    d
a  1   NaN NaN  1
ss NaN 2   NaN  2
cc 3  NaN NaN  3
aa NaN 4   NaN  4
ww NaN 5   NaN  5
ss NaN NaN 6    6
aa NaN NaN 7    7
g  NaN NaN 8    8
j  9   NaN NaN  9
```

For the numbers, it is not in integer. It is in np.float64. The integers are for clear example. you may assume the numbers are like 32065431243556.62, 763835218962767.8 Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can replace the NA by 0 and sum up the rows.

```
df['d'] = df[['a', 'b', 'c']].fillna(0).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, there are also columns which might contain numbers, is it possible to limit the summation only occurs in column a,b,c? @phi

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it's not nessary to use `fillna`, `sum` can transform the `NAN` elements to zeros automatically.

I'm a python newcomer as well,and I suggest maybe you should read the pandas cookbook first.

The code is:

```
df['Total']=df[['a','b','c']].sum(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) over `axis=1`:

```
df['D'] = df.ffill(1).iloc[:, -1].astype(int)

print(df)

     a    b    c  D
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1
1  NaN  2.0  NaN  2
2  3.0  NaN  NaN  3
3  NaN  4.0  NaN  4
4  NaN  5.0  NaN  5
5  NaN  NaN  6.0  6
6  NaN  NaN  7.0  7
7  NaN  NaN  8.0  8
8  9.0  NaN  NaN  9
```

Of course, if you have `float` values, `int` conversion is not required.

Answer (score 0):

if there is only one value per row as given example, you can use the code below to dropna for each row and assign the remaining value to column d

```
df['d']=df.apply(lambda row: row.dropna(), axis=1)
```